# CSS - background image for UI Kit

Tags: html, css

I've tried to modify background image of a div ...

```
        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">

                <div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center" style="background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') 50% 0 no-repeat; height: 450px;">
                    <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle uk-width-1-2">
                        <h1 class="uk-heading-large">Games are life, games are love.</h1>
                        <p class="uk-text-large">If you are a trully gamer and a lover of fps/moba/rpg you are in the right place. We are a big community of gaming, we sell games and help you to get the latest ones you would like to have.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

This `<div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center"` it's the div i need to modify.

If i replace background: url with background-image: url() it doesn't work, i have the image i want in folder images where website is placed.

Any idea what could I do ? i searched this problem .. i tried a lil bit with CSS in uikit.css, nothing works.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: backgroundImage doesn't work with encoded format. You need to provide the relative path to your image this to work.

Comment: Are you using javascript to do this ?

Comment: So, Randika, what would you suggest ? To upload my image i would like to use there and copy the link ? I know this way it works for sure.

Comment: Can you post the code of css having background-image .. Possible issue can be permission of file ( can you open the image in browser? ), or filepath may not be correct, or you might be providing wrong image name( check for capital letters in image name )

Comment: @Albert-VasileŞerban directly use  background: url();

Comment: Yash, I need to build a website using this UI kit, a project for university, it's not like i ask you guys to solve my homework for final exam, i need some help because my teacher is useless :), he just posts some links and go on, do these homeworks ... it's not ok... I ask you because i'm not that advanced in CSS3/CSS or HTML, i'm a C, C# programmer :) and work in this domain. I need just a lil bit help to understand few concepts. 

I do not know where should be in .js , i have some files with .js but i doubt is there, i checked and i don't find something like that.

Comment: Could you check this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/egorbatik/fFQC6/

Comment: @Santosh i use proper the command, i use it for body also and it works just fine with the path i give (background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg'); ) ---> this is from body .

For this div class ... i cannot write a good css lines to work.. And yes, i can open in browser that image.

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake i've checked it, doesn't really helps me at all... i need just to figure out why it doesn't work a simple css command ...

Comment: @Santosh also i've tried to do this in css : 


.uk-vertical-align .uk-text-center
{
  background-image: url('../images/firstpage.jpg'); 
 
} 

No result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, it's work just see this snippet with black body.

Your data image it's just a color, no content.

If you want to call image in a folder try to make

`background: url('./folder/path_to_your_img')`

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">

                <div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center" style="background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') 50% 0 no-repeat; height: 450px;">
                    <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle uk-width-1-2">
                        <h1 class="uk-heading-large">Games are life, games are love.</h1>
                        <p class="uk-text-large">If you are a trully gamer and a lover of fps/moba/rpg you are in the right place. We are a big community of gaming, we sell games and help you to get the latest ones you would like to have.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So, let me see if i got it right, my project has the following path for images 

uikit proiect/images/firstpage.jpg ( the file i would like to use as  background image for that grid ) so i need 

background: url('./images/firstpage.jpg') ?? 

index.html is in uikit project folder :)

Comment: @Albert-VasileŞerban Exact if your index.html is in the folder project the url will be background: url('./images/firstpage.jpg')

Comment: @Albert-VasileŞerban why you check good response for the other with a wrong code ? x)

Comment: sorry, i checked yours first. I'm sorry :) ! My fault here. Thank you again for helping me out to find the solution and have a better understanding of css.

Answer (score 0):

Try This this will help you.

```css
.uk-vertical-align{

background-image:url("https://zellox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/background-image-in-html.jpg");
height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">

                <div class="uk-vertical-align uk-text-center">
                    <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle uk-width-1-2">
                        <h1 class="uk-heading-large">Games are life, games are love.</h1>
                        <p class="uk-text-large">If you are a trully gamer and a lover of fps/moba/rpg you are in the right place. We are a big community of gaming, we sell games and help you to get the latest ones you would like to have.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                            <a class="uk-button uk-button-large" href="#">Button</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

write Your image path instead of (https://zellox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/background-image-in-html.jpg)